# Calling a DLL's extern function from inside a class function

Tags: c++, c, dll, dllexport

I have an example.cpp file that includes example.h in Windows. In the file example.h there is a function declared as

```
   //example.h  
   _EXTERN S16BIT _DECL function();
```

The function is externed from a DLL. In my example.cpp file I have a class `myclass` that I want to call the `function()` from the member function of the class `classfunc()` so,

```
  //example.cpp
  class myclass{
  public:
    classfunc(){
    function(); 
  }

 }
```

It compiles well but when it runs it gives me an access violation exception. I know it is wrong but don't know the solution.

EDITED: _EXTERN is defined as empty;

```
   #define _EXTERN
```

_DECL is defines as;

```
   #define _DECL __stdcall
```

S16BIT 2 bytes

Comment: What do `_EXTERN`, `S16BIT` and `_DECL` mean?

Comment: Currently impossible to say. We don't know what the macros expand to. And we don't have a specification for `function`.

Comment: You'll have to get more specific about...everything.

Comment: Ok. So where is the function implemented?

Comment: Your C++ code is wrong too. That's can't be the real code: classfunc doesn't have a return type specified.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you would like to call/consume pure C function , function() , from a DLL.
Please note that `__stdcall` is the calling convention for C++ functions, you should have use `__cdecl`

In your h file declare your function like this

```
extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) signed short function();
```

Comment: This is not helpful, or accurate. Languages don't have calling conventions and it's nonsense to say that stdcall is the C++ calling convention. And dllexport is what you do when implementing the function.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan instead of saying _nonsense_ please try being more constructive ... when I say C++ convention I should have said "how C++ instance method are being called" (I meant here to the convention of passing this in RCX/ECX and the stack clean up regime which of course isn't relevant when one codes in C). In case Bar as control over the DLL he/she can change its prototype hence I've mentioned the dllexport and not dllimport

Comment: C++ methods can be called with any calling convention. And stdcall is very rare. It's generally used for interop. Register calling conventions, fastcall, can be used in any language. stdcall doesn't use registers, parameters go on the stack. Stack clean up is absolutely relevant for C.